# How to maintain more than 7 active BLE connections on android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am trying to get about 50 devices to connect to my android tablet and have them actively send notification to the android tablet anytime there is something to notify.

To receive notifications I am assuming I need to maintain an active connection to the device. I also read that there is a limitation of 7 devices that can connect with an android device. Is this really true ? if true is there a workaround for me to be able to have connections to all the devices ?

Thanks 
-Naveen

Comment: Even a single medium specs computer can handle few connections, how much more is an android device ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hardware limitation. Most consumer phone's Bluetooth radio can only support a few devices, with most of them doing about 7, although it can go up to 12-13.

While this limits the number you can connect do for a master-slave network, you could do a scattered network with no limit, with some clients acting as bridges between different master-client networks.